# Strange background on desktop with Nvidia driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, i3-wm

I installed the base system from 16.04's mini.iso and am using i3. Whenever I go to a new desktop,

[image: I see this image in the background]

I'm using the nvidia 387 drivers, if that's relevant. It's a new install so I'm still trying out things, but everything else seems to be working fine. I can launch the nvidia-settings program, but am not sure if the problem would be a setting in there.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Am I going mad or is that the Windows 10 restart screen in the lower right? I'm dual booting, but how's that even possible?

Comment: That's just screen corruption; the video memory buffer that is being displayed has some leftover content from what was displayed before.  I assume you dual boot Windows.

Comment: This screen may indicate that Your graphics card memory is failing or try different nvidia binary drivers, the latest one is `390.42`.